# apply function doesn't work

Tags: r, replace, apply

I have a data frame that has some empty entries. I set the

`options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

so that I can change the empty cells. I then wrote the following code:

`apply(my_data[,6:65],2, function(x) x[which(x=='')]<-0)`

, hoping that it replaces all the empty cells with zeros. But it isn't working!
Note that `my_data` has 65 columns and columns 1:5 contain string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: functions in R don't operate in the global environment (unless forced to). And `apply` function does work, you just have no idea what it does

Comment: You do know that functions like this don't edit an array in place, right? Are you assigning the results of the apply somewhere?

Comment: Don't use `apply` on a `data.frame`. `apply` will convert it to a matrix, as it says in `?apply`.

Comment: In this case, any suggestion for an efficient way to do this task beside writing a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `apply`, just use `[<-` with logical indexing

```
my_data[my_data==""] <- 0
```